# Making a page inaccessible through URL, but accessible through link on page

Tags: .htaccess, url

on my site I have this program that I want only members to be able to access. I want the page to be inaccessible directly by typing in the URL, but members should be able to access it through a link in a "Members Only" section of the website. My skill level is a little above beginner. Thank you!!

Comment: Please provide some code so we can get a better idea of your problem

Comment: My site is a WordPress site. The individual WP pages are protected through a plugin. The page that I want to be hidden is an HTM File  that is the result of a converted Excel File. I uploaded it to the same directory as index.php. This page I want to be visible only to members, and while that is provided through a WP plugin, I need a way to protect this page. I want the page to not be accessible when one enters it into the address bar, only through a clicked link. I uploaded a .htaccess file to the directory of the HTM file and inserted the line `Deny from all` but that denies everybody.